# How to throw an exception in Jenkins pipeline when two parameters are same

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

This used to work for me, but it is not working now. Could you please help me?

```
if(approvalMap1 == approvalMap2) {
                throw new Exception("Moratorium approvers are the same. Aborting deployment")
            }
```

Trying to compare the two values and if it matches then it throws an exception and Jenkins pipeline stops.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Does it go into the `if` condition?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for checking my message.
so it goes into the if condition, I tried printing some lines in the if loop so which it is doing but I were actually looking/thinking that it will give me this line which I had written inside the brackets of **throw new Exception**("Moratorium approvers are the same. Aborting deployment")

Comment: Hello Komal welcome to stackoverflow, please edit your question to make it more precise, the answer section is only for answers. For chatting or responding you have the comment section just under your question. Have a good day :)